# Error while trying to generate rspec_helper.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

This is the output when i try `rails generate rspec:install` . I already installed `Capybara` and loaded it in Gemfile.

```
$ rails generate rspec:install
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.0
Could not find generator rspec:install.
```

Can anyone help me in this topic?

Comment: Did you already add rspec-rails to your Gemfile and run bundle install?

Comment: Thanks very much. It helped on me. But I'm still getting that WARNING!!! What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried re-installing Nokogiri?

```
gem uninstall nokogiri
gem install nokogiri
```

See if that helps.